# opening an ionic App second time on iOS, app not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, load

I have developing hybrid `ionic app`, its working fine for `android` . In `iOS` , for first time when Open app its works perfect but after closing and re-open, app becomes hang. no any data load in app.

I have installed this **plugins** :

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.0 "Camera"

cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"

cordova-plugin-console 1.0.6 "Console"

cordova-plugin-device 1.1.5 "Device"

cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.3 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"

cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.0 "InAppBrowser"

cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"

cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"

cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser 0.2.17 "ThemeableBrowser"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3-dev "Whitelist"

cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.7 "SocialSharing"

cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"

ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: are you getting any console logs in safari?

Comment: no, i can' get neither console nor errors in safari..

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

We had this exact issue!

It was to do with ionic auto updates. It would download some update on the first app run and apply it on the second app run.

We fixed it by removing the `cordova-plugin-ionic` plugin as we didn't actually want the functionality.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic
```

Comment: It worked, but breaks live-reload.

Comment: I believe I had some problems with this plugin, but also there were errors in the code so the line the hides the splash was not called. I was able to get them using livereload and --consolelogs arg to debug the lines of code being executed.